# Prometheus state down - WSL

Tags: docker, prometheus

I'm currently following [Learn Docker in a Month of Lunches](https://diamol.net/); Chapter 9 consists of running Prometheus to monitor, however, I am unable to connect to localhost.

Preliminary info:

- Docker v. 20.10.17
- WSL 2

`deamon.json` is following:

```json
{
"metrics-addr" : "0.0.0.0:9323",
"experimental": true
}
```

Startup command had the following output:

```bash
systemctl --user start docker-desktop
> Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I am able to run Docker Deamon using `service docker start`.

When trying to run Prometheus using the following commands:

```
hostIP=$(ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}')
docker container run -e DOCKER_HOST=$hostIP -d -p 9090:9090 diamol/prometheus:2.13.1
```

This is the output:
[image]

What I've tried already is changing `-e DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1`, however, here I also get an error:
[image]

I attempted to following the documentation provided by Prometheus, but that didn't lead to a desirable result.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the project but familiar with Docker and Prometheus. Your question suggests that, when you run `docker container run`, the `-e DOCKER_HOST=$hostIP` should be replaced by the host's IP. The fact that the Prometheus targets continue to include `DOCKER_HOST` is wrong. Do you get a valid looking IP from `echo $hostIP` (after running the first command? If you have `curl` installed, can you `curl http://localhost:9323/metrics`?

Comment: @DazWilkin When running `echo $hostIP` I get value 1000; I have attempted force assigning the IP Address; finding it using `hostname -I`, however that did not help. Lastly `curl` command timesout without any response from the server, so I am guessing docker is startup without `deamon.json`

Comment: Yes, I think that `hostIP=$(ip route get 1 ...)` command isn't portable and it's not working for you. I think the intent is to provide your host's IP address. You **should** be able to use localhost or `127.0.0.1` instead i.e. `hostIP=localhost`. The second problem is that the `prometheus.yaml` **should** be updated to replace the hard-coded `DOCKER_HOST` value. Are you missing a step somewhere? It's unclear how this is expected to work but the `docker run --env=DOCKER_HOST=$hostIP` suggests that the container's environment expects `DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: Were you able to `curl localhost:9323/metrics`? Is so, try manually replacing the `DOCKER_HOST` reference in `prometheus.yaml` to `localhost`.

Comment: @DazWilkin 

1. I hard coded 127 to `hostIP` nothing helped sadly.

2. I followed https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/prometheus/ set up, all worked fine, but can't access `localhost:9323` or `localhost:9090`; neither one works out. 

3. curl results in `Connection Refused`; but! 9090/metrics produced the prometheus output after the step 2! (though still can't access it via browser).

Comment: It should the full IP address i.e. `127.0.0.1` but, if `localhost` doesn't work, then that likely won't either. I'm outta ideas.

Comment: @DazWilkin same I am guessing that's the beauty of applying linux logic on WSL. I am guessing I will be fully on desktop app now.

Comment: It should work fine on WSL. The challenge is, I don't use WSL and so I don't understand the nuances. Hopefully someone else here can help you.